# How to change the font size of a grid title - ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, frameworks, grid, title

I'm new to Ext but after several researches and questions on Stack Overflow, I succeeded to add pictures in grid rows, headers rows, to change font-size, font-color of header titles, etc. But I still don't know how to change the font-size and so of the main title of the panel.
I succeeded to put a picture into the title panel by adding direct CSS, but not much.

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',


alias: 'widget.userlist',


cls: 'overall', 


title: 'XXX // DEMO <img class="title-icon" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:10px; " src="xxx/xxx/xxx.png"/> '
```

It might be a simple question to answer ! Thanks a lot :-)
Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normally `.x-panel-header-text-default` CSS class that controls panel header font styles.
If you navigate to a panel header in Firebug inspector you may see:

```
.x-panel-header-text-default {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 17px;
}
```

So you can override that rule in your CSS, or you can say take advantage of [headerCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Header-property-headerCls) config option to specify your CSS class.

Comment: But I don't get how to use the headerCls. I wrote headerCls: 'texttitle'in my View file and .texttitle .x-panel-header-text { in my CSS file, but it does not work :(

Comment: Inspect your CSS styles on the header's `span` element in Firebug. You will see why your styles do not apply. For example, they may have lesser priority than the original styles, in that case you'll need to set `!important` suffix on your styles.